# JNI Call JavaGUI from C++

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, java-native-interface

I am using VS2015 and I am trying to host a java GUI Application from c++, so that I can embed the c++ code in my WPF App (Container). So I started playing around with JNI, but without success so far. Could you tell me if this idea could work and what the error in my code could be.
I know there are already a few posts about this topic but non of them helped me.

The C++ code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\include\jni.h"
#include "ToolbarFrame2.h"
JNIEnv* create_vm() 
{
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options[0].optionString = "-    Djava.class.path=
        d:\EclipseProjects\SwingTest01\bin";
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env) 
{
    jclass helloWorldClass;
    jmethodID mainMethod;


    helloWorldClass = env->FindClass("ToolbarFrame2");

    mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(helloWorldClass, 
    "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(helloWorldClass, mainMethod);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    JNIEnv* env = create_vm();
    invoke_class(env);
}
```

And this is the java class:

```
public class ToolbarFrame2 extends JFrame {

public ToolbarFrame2() {

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");

    quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    this.createLayout(quitButton);
    setTitle("Simple example");
    setSize(300, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

    Container pane = getContentPane();
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
    pane.setLayout(gl);

    gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
    );

    gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
    );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ToolbarFrame2 ex = new ToolbarFrame2();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

I made a Header-file from my JAVA program (with javah) and included the jni.h and the jni_md.h. Also I added a additional dependency to my project in VS (in Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies):

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\lib

But when I try to compile my c++ code this error gets thrown while compiling:

> LNK1104   cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\lib.obj'

I don't know what else to include or what I did wrong (also this file doesn't even exist in that directory).

Answer (score 0):

Additional Dependencies should be:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\lib\jvm.lib
```